# My .desktop file doesn't launch application

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to create a launcher

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
Name=PulseSecure
Icon=
```

this is my .desktop files configuration for now , if I execute the command "/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi" it works perfectly but when I click to open the .desktop file nothing happens. any ideas?

Comment: Provide more detail. Launcher on the desktop has to be "activated" using an option in the right-click menu. Alternatively, launcher in .local/share/application will be included in the application overview to be launched there.

Comment: Sorry, the desktop file is in /usr/share/applications and "Allow executing files  as program" activated. Ubuntu 20. I s there a way to see logs? I can see a terminal showing up and closing too quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution I changed the Exec line to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
```

Comment: I tried this but still silent, may you give little more hint?